# In Tridion 2009, is it possible to suppress the Advanced dialog of the RTF image tool?

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

In Rich text format areas, our site design dictates only a couple of possibilities for styling an image. These possibilities are offered via a FormatAreaStyles configuration.

If the author selects the image, opens the image tool, and clicks the Advanced button, they will be offered the possibility to choose from various formatting options, which are then saved in the HTML as inline CSS attributes. On save, these are then removed by the XSLT, which is confusing for the users.

To prevent this confusion, I would prefer not to show the Advanced features at all. What, then, is the preferred technique for customising the 2009 gui in this way? I recall that in earlier versions it was common to modify the RTF user interface via the XSLT, but I suspect this won't work for my scenario. Perhaps a GUI extension could be used, which used JavaScript to make the advanced button invisible. Does anyone know of such an implementation available in the public domain? What other techniques might be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John suggested on one of my questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703177/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-upload-mm-component-button-from-the-sdl-tridion-2/10706405#10706405), you could try hiding it using CSS and the !important attribute to override the default CSS. That may be easier than using JavaScript, but not An ideal scenario.