# Is it possible to remove the "Upload MM Component" button from the SDL Tridion 2011 Ribbon

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

This button causes a lot of problems for my client, as it always uses a predefined Schema. I can't find a way to remove this button with my Editor config. I have done this with other buttons, but these buttons are implemented in some sort of sub-group.

On my personal sandbox machine, I tried removing the commented out control in the extract of the ../WebUI/Editors/CME/Controls/Toolbars/Tabs/CreateRibbonPage.ascx file shown below:

```xml
<c:RibbonSplitButton runat="server" CommandName="NewComponent" 
   Title="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, NewComponent %>" 
   Label="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, NewComponent %>"
   ID="NewComponentBtn1">
  <c:RibbonContextMenuItem runat="server" ID="NewComponentCMI2" 
     Command="NewComponent" 
     Title="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, NewComponent %>" 
     Label="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, NewComponent %>" />
  <c:RibbonContextMenuItem runat="server" ID="NewMultimediaComponentCMI2" 
     Command="NewMultimediaComponent"  
     Title="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, NewMultimediaComponent %>" 
     Label="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, NewMultimediaComponent %>" />
  <!--
  <c:RibbonUploadContextMenuItem runat="server" 
     ID="NewBasicMultimediaComponentCMI2" Command="NewBasicMultimediaComponent"  
     Title="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, NewBasicMultimediaComponent %>"
     Label="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, NewBasicMultimediaComponent %>" />
  -->
</c:RibbonSplitButton>
```

This seems to have the desired result, but I imagine that this will probably invalidate our support agreement if I did this in a customer environment. Is this possible to do in a supported way, or do I have to hack the UI files like this to achieve my goal?

Comment: My CME.config (T2011 SP1) has a commented-out section starting with `<!-- Upload button settings (create mm component from file).` that seems to set multimedia types and schema settings. Not sure if that's only a 1:1 mapping, though. I'd be interested in replacing the `New Component` group altogether to note hide the multimedia option (two small buttons instead of the drop-down to see mm).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the solutions is to create extension for the `NewBasicMultimediaComponent` command, which extends `isAvailable` and `isEnabled` methods and returns `false` for them. In this case "Upload MM Component" still will be present as an option for "New Component" button, but it will be disabled.

Answer (score 6):

I've used css to hide the display of ribbon items before.  Purely because I couldn't find the appropriate solution.

Comment: Scary... but an interesting approach. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I've also seen this approach in the Tridion PE. It seems to work quite well, even if it wasn't what I needed for my demo ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding this answer because I needed to do something similar with a complete ribbon toolbar.

I needed to remove the complete ribbon toolbar "Create" in order to add a simpler version of it and it seems you can do the removal part by creating a new extension and use this in your extensions config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge" xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration" xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions" xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu" xmlns:edt="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge">
    <resources>
        <cfg:groups />
    </resources>
    <definitionfiles />
    <extensions>
        <ext:editorextensions>
            <ext:editorextension target="CME">
                <ext:editurls />
                <ext:listdefinitions />
                <ext:itemicons />
                <ext:taskbars />
                <ext:commands />
                <ext:commandextensions />
                <ext:contextmenus />
                <ext:lists />
                <ext:tabpages>
                </ext:tabpages>
                <ext:toolbars>
                </ext:toolbars>
                <ext:ribbontoolbars>
                    <ext:remove>
                        <ext:extension id="CreatePage">
                            <ext:apply>
                                <ext:view name="DashboardView">
                                    <ext:control id="DashboardToolbar" />
                                </ext:view>
                            </ext:apply>
                        </ext:extension>
                    </ext:remove>
                </ext:ribbontoolbars>
                <ext:extendedareas />
            </ext:editorextension>
        </ext:editorextensions>
        <ext:dataextenders />
    </extensions>
    <commands />
    <contextmenus />
    <localization />
    <settings>
        <dependencies />
        <defaultpage />
        <editurls />
        <listdefinitions />
        <theme>
            <path>/Themes/</path>
        </theme>
        <customconfiguration />
    </settings>
</Configuration>
```

To make this work for buttons you probably can do the same thing (haven't tested this), by providing the button id in the ext:extension id attribute.