# add ribbon button like "Open" with drop-down options

Tags: tridion

I'm hoping this is just a simple pointer to something existing which I couldn't locate via google.

What our business folks want is a button much like the "Open" button which once clicked, gives a pull-down with 3 options. I can't quite figure out how to pull that off.

I can easily add a button. I can even add a stack of 3 "small" buttons vertically. I can't quite figure out the drop-down from large button. One of our folks thought he did this a long time ago, but can't find any evidence to prove it. ;)

Can anyone point me to what I missed? or, anyone confirm that it's not possible?

thanks,

~Warner

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately that is implemented in a different way than how normal buttons are added to the ribbon. I am basing this on the answers I received here:

[Is it possible to remove the "Upload MM Component" button from the SDL Tridion 2011 Ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703177/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-upload-mm-component-button-from-the-sdl-tridion-2)

It seems you will need to create an ASCX to achieve this.

Comment: I recently have been looking into "extensions that require ASCX" and they're not as "scary" as I initially though. Just ignore all the advanced stuff that Microsoft does with them and think of them as ***"HTML fragments"***.

Comment: that's sort of what I figured. I've been playing with it a bit here today, trying to study how CreateRibbonPage.ascx is created and registered and I'm no closer to understanding how to really get started.
I see in the CME.config where a group is defined and points to /Controls/Toolbars/Tabs/CreateRibbonPage.js
I am not seeing how an ascx ties in, or how to "copy paste" the CreateRibbonPage.js to get started on a similar button. are y'all able to give me a little more to go on to get started? thanks.